# Could not load type Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.SetField

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am using Bot Framework SDK v-4 and trying to use `QnAMakerService`.

I have the `BotService.cs` where I have the `QnAMakerService` instatiations. While, initiating the `QnAMakerService` I get an error in my Visual Studio Diagnostics window:

> could not load type Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.SetField

Below is my code. I have commented the line where I get the error:

```
public BotServices(BotConfiguration botConfiguration)
{
    foreach (var service in botConfiguration.Services)
    {
        switch (service.Type)
        {
            case ServiceTypes.QnA:
                {
                    var qna = (Microsoft.Bot.Configuration.QnAMakerService)service;
                    if (qna == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("The QnA service is not configured correctly in your '.bot' file.");
                    }

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(qna.KbId))
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("The QnA KnowledgeBaseId ('kbId') is required to run this sample. Please update your '.bot' file.");
                    }

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(qna.EndpointKey))
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("The QnA EndpointKey ('endpointKey') is required to run this sample. Please update your '.bot' file.");
                    }

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(qna.Hostname))
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("The QnA Host ('hostname') is required to run this sample. Please update your '.bot' file.");
                    }

                    string defaultMessage = "Sorry no answer found.";
                    QnAMakerAttribute qnAMakerAttribute = new QnAMakerAttribute(qna.EndpointKey, qna.KbId, defaultMessage, 40, 5, <end_point>);
                    var qnaMakerService = new Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker.QnAMakerService(qnAMakerAttribute); // Error is here
                    qnaMakerServices.Add(qna.Name, qnaMakerService);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I had used native `Http` calls earlier with the same endpoint and it worked fine. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you may have a mismatch in dependency versions. Check your Microsoft.Bot.*.dll versions and ensure they're all equal

Comment: @Daniel But I updated all the dependent nuget packages to the latest stable version. Shouldn't it work?

Comment: a lot of things *should* work. I would still double check

Comment: @Daniel You may be right. Out of all the other dlls this is the only one which is not having the same version. I will check more on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SouvikGhosh Daniel is correct, there's a mismatch in dependency versions going on here.

As you see in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.internals.fibers.fiber-1?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0#applies-to), the `Fiber` class applies to `Microsoft.Bot.Builder v3`.

What you need for `QnAMaker` in v4 is `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA` for C#:
https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA

---

TL;DR just make sure you have only v4 dependencies and not a mix of v3 and v4